# In cvs,how do i search for the comments that are present inside a particular ,v file

Tags: cvs

I need to grep for specific comments from a cvs file and give an output based on that in a python file.

For example, if there is a comment saying "deleted" then i need a command which outputs the comment so that I  can assign that output to a variable and do an re.search on the contents of that variable in my python file.

Comment: You shouldn't be parsing the repository files (`*,v`) manually. You should use cvs commands to get the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that by "comment", you mean the log message provided with `cvs commit`.

Given just a `*,v` file, you can use the `rlog` command (part of rcs, not part of cvs) to get a log that will show all the commit messages.

But ordinarily it should be part of a CVS repository; in that case, `cvs log` will do the same thing.

Both `rlog` and `cvs log` produce very similar plain-text output that should be reasonably easy to parse.

That's about all I can come up with based on the information you've given us. Provide a more detailed question, and we can probably give you a more detailed answer.

**UPDATE :**

If by "comments" you mean text in the files themselves rather than commit messages, you can extract individual versions of the file using a command like this:

```
cvs update -p -r1.23 filename
```

The `-p` option tells `cvs update` to print the contents of the file to stdout.

Shameless self-promotion: My own [get-versions](https://github.com/Keith-S-Thompson/get-versions) tool lets you grab multiple versions of a file in a single command (it currently works with RCS, CVS, and Git).

Extracting a particular comment and storing it in a variable will require more work and, as I said, a more detailed question.